# Is there a way for a docker pipeline file to determine the image of the child node it runs on?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to be able to dynamically provision docker child nodes for builds and have the configuration / setup of those nodes be part of the Jenkinsfile groovy script it uses.

Limitations of the current setup of jobs means Jenkins has one node/executor (`master`) and I'd like to support using Docker for nodes to alleviate this bottleneck.

I've noticed there's two ways of using a docker container as a node:

1. You can use the [agent section in your pipeline file](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) which allows you to specify an image to use. As part of this, you can target a specific node  which supports running docker images, but I haven't gotten that far as to see what happens.
2. You can use the [Jenkins Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) which allows you to add a Docker Cloud in Jenkins' configuration. It allows you to specify a label which, when used as part of a build, will spawn a container in that "cloud" from the image chosen in the cloud configuration. In this case, the "cloud" is the docker instance running on the Jenkins server.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like you can use both together - using the label but specifying a docker image in the configuration (1) where the label matches a docker cloud template configuration (2) does not seem to work and instead produces a label not found error during the build.

Ideally I'd prefer the control to be in the pipeline groovy file so the configuration is stored with the application (1), not with the Jenkins server (2). However, it *suggests* that if I use the `agent` section and provide a docker image, *it still must target an existing executor first* (i.e. `master`) which will cause other builds to queue until the current build is complete.

I'm at a point of migrating builds, so not all builds can support using a docker container as the node yet, and builds will have issues when ran in parallel on the `master` node.

**Is there a way for a docker pipeline file to determine the image of the child node it runs on?**

There are a few options I have considered but not attempted yet:

1. Migrate jobs to run on the "docker cloud" until all jobs support running on child container nodes, then move the configuration from Jenkins to the pipeline build file for each job and turn on parallel builds on the `master` node.
2. Attempt to add a new node configuration which is effectively a copy of `master` (uses the same server, just different location). Configure it to support parallel builds, and have all migrated jobs target the node explicitly during builds.

Comment: hey, I have a similar problem where I want my jenkinsfile to have server on which to create container from dockerfile, both are present in repository.

Did you found any solution or any help in this regard?

Comment: Hi @ateebahmed, sadly not. In the end I bit the bullet and ran them on the master node serially, it took more time, but the infrastructure I was using at the time didn't support what I wanted it to do.

Nevertheless, if there's a a solution you do end up finding, I'd love to hear about it!